# Device Manager not found in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I have just download the lastest version of Android Studio, the Iguana 2023.2.1, but after some time using it, I can't find the device manager anywhere. I installed some devices from my last Android Studio, so they still worked perfectly. Does anybody knows how to solve this problem? Please help me!
[image: The image is my Android Studio.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the old UI back (device manager on the right hand side displayed as a labeled, clickable tab), you can go into settings > appearance> New UI and toggle off the New UI.

In the new UI, there is an icon in the same bar on the right side with an icon that looks similar to a smartphone overlayed with the android logo. You can also access the device manager via the device drop-down box next to the Run Module button (top right bar).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have found the Device Manager. I hope you will reply lots of useful answers in the future!